# Promise execute order

Tags: javascript, node.js

Why the output result is  "1, 2, 3, 4", not "1,4,2,3"?

If you have a answer, pls give a separate answer below, not a comment,
explaining which run of the JavaScript event loop do which thing is appreciated，such as:

(1)..

(2)..

(3)..

Thanks!

```
const wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

wait(0).then(() => console.log(4));
Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log(2)).then(() => console.log(3));
console.log(1); // 1, 2, 3, 4
```

Comment: Why do you invoke `wait` without the mandatory argument?

Comment: Because `.then()` handlers on an already resolved promise are called before `setTimeout()` handlers.

Comment: asynchronous code is asynchronous - if your intent is to somehow be able to predict the order of asynchronous code, then you have a better chance of staying dry whilst peeing into the wind :p

Comment: I have changed wait() to wait(0). the time is not important, and the result is same.